# unwanted content deletion by updating multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

table `params` has two columns - `what` and `story`.

Updating multiple rows with different values:

```
function save($a, $b, $c, $d, $e){
    global $db;
    $sql = "    
        update params set story = case what 
        when 'art_before' then :a 
        when 'art_left' then :b 
        when 'art_middle' then :c 
        when 'art_right' then :d 
        when 'art_after' then :e 
        end";
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute([
        ":a" => $a, ":b" => $b, ":c" => $c, ":d" => $d, ":e" => $e
    ]);
}
```

It works but the column `story` where `what` is `home` (not in the above list) is also updated, i.e. its content is deleted.

Any help?

Comment: Add `else story` so that if no case matches, then the value will be the original content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how `CASE` works. In the absence of any matching condition an `ELSE` is executed (**implicit** in this case), that returns a `null`  value.

If you don't want to update it when no explicit condition is met, I would set its value to the current value using an **explicit** `ELSE`, as in:

```
update params set story = case what 
    when 'art_before' then :a 
    when 'art_left' then :b 
    when 'art_middle' then :c 
    when 'art_right' then :d 
    when 'art_after' then :e 
    else story -- added an explicit ELSE 
    end
```

Alternatively, you can just update the rows that match one condition, adding a `WHERE` clause:

```
update params set story = case what 
  when 'art_before' then :a 
  when 'art_left' then :b 
  when 'art_middle' then :c 
  when 'art_right' then :d 
  when 'art_after' then :e 
  end
where what in ('art_before', 'art_left', 'art_middle', 'art_right', 'art_after')
```

Comment: `else story` - will this keep all the rest of rows untached?

Comment: Yep, you'll "update" the rows with the current value in case there's no match. A no-op.

Comment: but that's a large job in vain - updating rows with existing values, Is there a way to jump over them?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's optimal to update only a subset of rows. See the second option.